# Looping back to my if statement after using a switch statement in conjunction with a do/while statement

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, switch-statement, do-while

Hello there fellow coders. Just a noob here that is currently stuck in a pickle.
I am coding a math training program, and am needing to loop back to my main menu.
There is an infinite loop i am having trouble getting out of. If the user keeps answering the correct answer, it just keeps on asking for another problem. Selecting yes will generate a new answer and will keep doing so (infinite). Selecting no will terminate the program.
How do i make is so if they select no, it takes the user back to the main menu?
Also, how to make it so if they select yes, the problem only loops a new equation at max 10 times before taking the user back to my main menu.

This is my Code:

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Random;

public class MathPracticeProgram
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Scenario: Make a practice program for Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, and Division. Include exit option as well.
        Random rand = new Random ();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int menu = (5);
        int num1, num2, user_answer, total;

        System.out.println("Math Practice Porgram");
        System.out.println("Please Input Your Choice via the number\n");
        System.out.println("1. Addition\n2. Subtraction\n 3. Multiplication\n 4. Division\n Exit Program by entering 0");
        System.out.println("\nYour choice:");
        menu = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n");

        //Menu Selection
        if (menu <= 5 || menu > 0)
        {
            switch(menu)
            {
                //Exit
                case 0:
                {
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using my math practice program.");
                }
                    break;
                //Addition  
                case 1:
                {
                    System.out.println("You have selected Addition");
                    String user_again;
                    do 
                    {
                        num1 = rand.nextInt(99);
                        num2 = rand.nextInt(99);
                        int counter = 0;

                        do
                        {
                            System.out.println("New solution to solve: ");
                            System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = ");

                            user_answer = scan.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("\n");
                            total = num1 + num2;

                            if(user_answer != total)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Incorrect...");
                                counter++;
                            }

                        }while (user_answer != total && counter < 3);
                        System.out.println("Correct! Do you want another problem? yes or no: ");
                        user_again = scan.next();

                    }while(user_again.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
                    System.out.println("\nChanging to Main Menu\n");
                }   
                        break;
                //Subtraction
                case 2:
                {

                }
                    break;
                //Multiplication
                case 3:
                {
                    System.out.println("Multiplication");
                }
                    break;
                //Division
                case 4:
                {
                    System.out.println("Division");
                }
                    break;

            }       
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You answered your own question: if you want to "loop back" to the main menu, you need a **loop**.  The code that displays the main menu, accepts the user's choice and acts on that choice _all_ needs to be inside of an overall loop.

Comment: How do i get back to the original if-statement after a user solves 10 questions or selects "no"? Looping back to that first if-statement is what is leaving me in a stump.

Comment: Like I said, there's no "looping back" without an actual loop statement.  Any chunk of code you might ever want to execute more than one time needs to be in the body of a loop.

Comment: You can try doing it by recursion. Shift your whole program under `public static void main` to a `static` method eg:- **mainMenu()** and call it whenever you need.